# Api Result Weirdness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, console, flickr

I have run the following in my Rails app:

```
Flickr.collections_list
```

The class and method is:

```
class Flickr

  require 'httparty'
  include HTTParty

  API_KEY         = '2fkjgdskjgksdjkgjrkbff3aee'
  SECRET          = '881fgregreg2b2'
  USER_ID         = '57rgrfgr266@N03'
  RESPONSE_FORMAT = 'json'
  base_uri          'http://api.flickr.com'

  # Get list of all collections
  def self.collections_list
    response = get("/services/rest/",
      :query => {
        method:          'flickr.collections.getTree',
        api_key:         API_KEY,
        user_id:         USER_ID,
        nojsoncallback:  1
      }
    )

    JSON.parse(response.to_json.gsub('\"', '"'))
  end

end
```

When running that in the console I get my result which looks fine but a bit of the way throguh the result I just get a semi colon. I can;t quit out of it, I can;t see the rest of the API result. What's going on?

> ```
> => {"rsp"=>
>   {"collections"=>
>     {"collection"=>
>       {"collection"=>
>         [{"collection"=>
>            [{"set"=>
>               [{"id"=>"7215fffff81735",
>                 "title"=>"Album title",
>                 "description"=>"Album title"},
>                {"id"=>"72145645ffff464564606",
>                 "title"=>"Album title",
>                 "description"=>
>                  "Album title"},
>                {"id"=>"721545646760",
>                 "title"=>"Album title",
>                 "description"=>
>                  "Album title"}],
>              "id"=>"5794562-721546456457291",
>              "title"=>"Album title",
>              "description"=>"",
>              "iconlarge"=>"/images/collection_default_l.gif",
>              "iconsmall"=>"/images/collection_default_s.gif"},
>             {"set"=>
>               [{"id"=>"72145645635562",
>                 "title"=>"Album title",
>                 "description"=>""},
>                {"id"=>"72164564561696",
>                 "title"=>"Album title",
>                 "description"=>""},
>                {"id"=>"72157464546",
>                 "title"=>"Album title",
>                 "description"=>""},
>                {"id"=>"72154564642",
>                 "title"=>"Album title",
>                 "description"=>""},
>                {"id"=>"7215762456456644",
>                 "title"=>
>                  "Album title",
>                 "description"=>""},
>                {"id"=>"721546456489442",
>                 "title"=>"Album title",
>                 "description"=>""},
>                {"id"=>"7215464568",
>                 "title"=>
>                  "Album title",
>                 "description"=>""},
>                {"id"=>"721574645638",
>                 "title"=>"Album title",
> :
> ```

I have changed all the id's and album names in the code but other than that it is an exact copy of the response.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. Just had to press the `Page Down` key and the rest of the result from Flickr was there all along!